# Rendering DataTable rows from json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, datatables

I am trying to render DataTable-rows from a json file, placed on the same directory. But unfortunately, the DataTable-Body stays empty, and no error is displayed in the console. [image]

Here is the (reduced) HTML-Code:

```
<table id="opTable">
    <thead>
      <tr><th class="partner_id">ID</th><th>ShortName</th><th>DisplayName</th><th>LogoUrl</th><th>Incent</th><th>JTS-URL</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the JavaScript I am using to load the data from the json file:

```
      <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('#onlinePartnerTable').DataTable({
             "ajax" : "../test2.json",
            "columns": [{
                "data": "pId"
            }, {
                "data": "shrName"
            }, {
                "data": "DplayName"
            }, {
                "data": "lgo"
            }, {
                "data": "inc"
            }, {
                "data": "featured"
            }]
        });
    });
  </script>
```

and here is a sample of my json file:

```
{
"partnerList": [ 
         {
            "shrname": "bchan",
            "Dplayname": "bchang-Shop",
            "pId": "id12345",
            "featured": "0",
            "lgo": "https://url.here.com/url",
            "inc": "1 to 1",
            "dets": {
                "tmage": "someUrl/here",
                "desp": "desciption",
                "jturl": "jtUrl/here",
                "jtbut": "Shop",
                "termy": [
                    {
                        "heady": "",
                        "body": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
         {
            "shrname": "hereIsIt",
            "Dplayname": "HereIs-Shop",
            "pId": "id65432",
            "featured": "0",
            "lgo": "https://url.here.com/url",
            "inc": "2 to 1",
            "dets": {
                "tmage": "someUrl/here",
                "desp": "desciption",
                "jturl": "jtUrl/here",
                "jtbut": "Shop",
                "termy": [
                    {
                        "heady": "",
                        "body": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
  ]
}
```

I am becomming this error now.. See the image below.

[image]

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: the data is not loaded in the Datatable.. The body stays empty

Comment: Then add that vital piece of information to your question.

Comment: Your data structure doesn't seem to match the structure used in the documentation [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html) or [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) (click the AJAX tab)

Comment: anyone has an idea how to do that right?

Comment: What are you trying to do with "dets" in there?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var t = [{
  "shrname": "bchan",
  "Dplayname": "bchang-Shop",
  "pId": "id12345",
  "featured": "0",
  "lgo": "https://url.here.com/url",
  "inc": "1 to 1",
  "dets": {
    "tmage": "someUrl/here",
    "desp": "desciption",
    "jturl": "jtUrl/here",
    "jtbut": "Shop",
    "termy": [{
      "heady": "",
      "body": ""
    }]
  }
}, {
  "shrname": "hereIsIt",
  "Dplayname": "HereIs-Shop",
  "pId": "id65432",
  "featured": "0",
  "lgo": "https://url.here.com/url",
  "inc": "2 to 1",
  "dets": {
    "tmage": "someUrl/here",
    "desp": "desciption",
    "jturl": "jtUrl/here",
    "jtbut": "Shop",
    "termy": [{
      "heady": "",
      "body": ""
    }]
  }
}];
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#opTable').DataTable({
    "aaData": t,
    "columns": [{
      "data": "pId"
    }, {
      "data": "shrname"
    }, {
      "data": "Dplayname"
    }, {
      "data": "lgo"
    }, {
      "data": "inc"
    }, {
      "data": "featured"
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="opTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="partner_id">ID</th>
      <th>ShortName</th>
      <th>DisplayName</th>
      <th>LogoUrl</th>
      <th>Incent</th>
      <th>JTS-URL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sounds good, but I am reading the data from a json file, that is the point. And not from a variable (var t)

Comment: I changed the question.. Now there is an error displayed, when I load the page, of which I made a screenshot and put it above. Do you have an idea @Krupesh?

Answer (score 0):

Based on one of the links Turnip provided in the comments, [Datatables Ajax Data Source (objects)](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html), your data should look like this:

```
{
  "data": [
        {
            "shrname": "bchan",
            "Dplayname": "bchang-Shop",
            "pId": "id12345",
            "featured": "0",
            "lgo": "https://url.here.com/url",
            "inc": "1 to 1",              
        },
         {
            "shrname": "hereIsIt",
            "Dplayname": "HereIs-Shop",
            "pId": "id65432",
            "featured": "0",
            "lgo": "https://url.here.com/url",
            "inc": "2 to 1",             
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the "dets" part of your data though

Comment: This should be the form that the JSON coming in should take then